# Can i use sendTotopic to make push notification to multiple device and if i want to send it to condition that all user that role=A how do i do?

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

and do i need to use token if i want to send notification to only user who have role=A?

here is my code `index.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();



exports.notifyDoctorregisTopic = functions.firestore.document('clinicreport/{reportId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const data = snapshot.data();

        // Check the conditions
        if (data.uid !== null && data.status === 'waiting') {
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'มีClinicสมัครมา',
                    body: 'A new clinic report is available',
                    clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                },
                data: {
                    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', // for background
                }
            };

            // Send the notification to the Doctorregis topic
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('Doctorregis', payload);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

i try this code and it send notification to all user.

Answer (score 1):

Topic messages are sent to all users that have subscribed for a topic.

> Topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.

Subscribe

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("roleA");
```

Send

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("roleA", payload);
```

See [Topic messaging on Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/topic-messaging) for details.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TU2UOEWn7EozJVlqHxnaj6Utg5W1F40Q/view?usp=sharing) this is my setting of that topic can i do like this?